# How to sort double objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an array. The data in the array is in the following format.

```
var test = [
    {
    "a" : {
        "order" : 100,
    }
  },
  {
    "b" : {
        "order" : 10,
    }
  },
  {
    "c" : {
        "order" : 1,
    }
  },
];
```

I want to sort this data according to order value. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the first property value and access the order property on that to compare.

```js
let test=[{a:{order:100}},{b:{order:10}},{c:{order:1}}];
test.sort((a, b)=>Object.values(a)[0].order - Object.values(b)[0].order);
console.log(test);
```

For a more generalized solution, you can create a key extractor function to get the value to compare by.

```js
let test=[{a:{order:100}},{b:{order:10}},{c:{order:1}}];
const getOrder = x => Object.values(x)[0].order;
test.sort((a, b)=>getOrder(a) - getOrder(b));
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JS custom sort from `Array.prototype.sort()`, reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Then you can sort by comparing the two element's `order`, but you still need to determine it's key/attribute (e.g.: `a` or `b` or `c`)

Here, you can use `Object.keys()` function and take the first key in the object, reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Here's a working example:

```js
var test = [
    {
    "a" : {
        "order" : 100,
    }
  },
  {
    "b" : {
        "order" : 10,
    }
  },
  {
    "c" : {
        "order" : 1,
    }
  },
];



//console.log(test);


test.sort((firstEl, secondEl) => { 
    var key1 = Object.keys(firstEl)[0];
    var key2 = Object.keys(secondEl)[0];
    return firstEl[key1].order - secondEl[key2].order
} );
console.log(test);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "c": {
      "order": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "b": {
      "order": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "a": {
      "order": 100
    }
  }
]
```